# Trying to get an int by subtracting a date from a date

Tags: c#, datetime, date

With this code:

```
public static bool PlatypusIsAFornightOrLessOld(int PlatypusID) {
const int FORTNIGHT = 14;
const string sql = @"SELECT PLATYPUSBIRTHDATE
            FROM PLATYPI 
            WHERE PLATYPUSID = :PLATYPUSID";
DateTime dt;
try {
    using (var ocmd = new OracleCommand(sql, oc)) {
        ocmd.Parameters.Add("PLATYPUSID", PlatypusID);
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ocmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    return (DateTime.Today - dt) <= FORTNIGHT;
} catch (Exception e) {
. . .
```

I'm getting: "Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int'" on the "return" line.

Comment: On a side note, a Fortnight is 14 days...

Comment: Ah, yes, what was I thinking (fortnight == 14, ! 20)

Comment: Oh, I was getting it mixed up with a "score" of days.

Comment: That accepted change hurts man.... just hurts...

Comment: @JT: Sorry, nothing personal!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have suggested going *from* the `TimeSpan` to the number of days. I would suggest it's cleaner to represent `FORTNIGHT` as a `TimeSpan` too. Alternatively, even better yet: work out the *deadline* as a `DateTime` and avoid the subtraction entirely:

```
public static bool PlatypusIsAFornightOrLessOld(int platypusId) {
    DateTime oneFortnightAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);

    ... SQL stuff ...

    return dt >= oneFortnightAgo;
}
```

Also, I hope that you haven't *really* got `catch(Exception e)` in your real code. You should almost *never* catch `Exception` - and definitely not in the same method which is doing SQL operations.

Comment: I've got quite a few catch(Exception e) in my code. Why is this bad, and especially so in SQL operations? Funny that Resharper doesn't complain about it. I'm not doubting you, Jon, just curious!

Comment: BTW, I knew what you meant, but it's actually AddDays()

Comment: @ClayShannon: Whoops - PlusDays is what we've got in Noda Time, which I believe is cleaner as it makes it more obvious that it returns the result of the operation, rather than mutating the existing value :) Catching `Exception` is bad in general as it's claiming to handle *anything* that goes wrong - even if it's stuff you really didn't expect, and don't want to try to handle. Normally only "top level" calls should be handling Exception (to abort the request but keep the server alive, for example) - not business calls which are doing actual SQL work.

Comment: What about catching Exception e just for logging and rethrowing? This is what I normally do (using log4net): log.Error(e, e); throw;

Comment: @ClayShannon: Yes, that's not too bad - other than cluttering up the place. (Why would you not do *that* at the top level?)

Comment: What think you of this, Jon, in an INSERT method:
 } catch { transaction.Rollback(); throw; }

Comment: @ClayShannon: I would *expect* that a `Transaction` would implement `IDisposable`, and would automatically roll back when disposed but not committed. (I'd have to check that with the relevant implementation, of course.) At that point, you just need a `using` statement.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do

```
return (DateTime.Today - dt).Days <= FORTNIGHT;
```

[Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) returns the number of full days of the timespan.  If you need fractional days, you would use TotalDays.